# Change endianness of entire struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, deserialization, endianness

I am writing a parser in C++ to parse a well defined binary file. I have declared all the required structs. And since only particular fields are of interest to me, so in my structs I have skipped non-required fields by creating char array of size equal to skipped bytes. So I am just reading the file in char array and casting the char pointer to my struct pointer. Now problem is that all data fields in that binary are in big endian order, so after typecasting I need to change the endianness of all the struct fields. One way is to do it manually for each and every field. But there are various structs with many fields, so it'll be very cumbersome to do it manually. So what's the best way to achieve this. And since I'll be parsing very huge such files (say in TB's), so I require a fast way to do this.

EDIT : I have use **attribute(packed)** so no need to worry about padding.

Comment: Note: you will also need to take padding into account.

Comment: You probably are going to have to do it for every field, yes, but you could generate code that does that from your structure definition .h files, and perhaps add comments for your code generator to pick up where there are exceptions to your default assumptions etc.

Comment: Best way is stop doing "reading the file in char array and casting the char pointer to my struct pointer.". You either will get padding issue or penalty of unaligned data access.

Comment: @Rup what do you recommend for code generation ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can do misaligned accesses with no penalty, and you don't mind compiler- or platform-specific tricks to control padding, this can work. (I assume you *are* OK with this since you mention `__attribute__((packed))`).

In this case the nicest approach is to write value wrappers for your raw data types, and use those instead of the raw type when declaring your struct in the first place. Remember the value wrapper must be trivial/POD-like for this to work. If you have a POSIX platform you can use `ntohs/ntohl` for the endian conversion, it's likely to be better optimized that whatever you write yourself.

If misaligned accesses are illegal or slow on your platform, you need to deserialize instead. Since we don't have reflection yet, you can do this with the same value wrappers (plus an `Ignore<N>` placeholder that skips N bytes for fields you're not interested), and declare them in a tuple instead of a struct - you can iterate over the members in a tuple and tell each to deserialize itself from the message.

Comment: “it's likely to be better optimized that whatever you write yourself” unlikely. CPUs have instruction for that, `bswap`. I don’t think a library function can be faster than a single CPU instruction, which is usable from C++ as `_bswap` and `_bswap64` intrinsics.

Comment: @Useless, writing own wrappers also came to my mind. My only concern is that creating wrapper objects over POD may have some overhead, though i think it should be not that much, but again I am working with TB's of data so I am a bit skeptic. And can you clarify that placeholder thing ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any overhead unless you do something odd, but you anyway need some manageable subset of the data to use for benchmarking, so you should really time both versions.

Comment: And the placeholder is just a type that can _consume_ the required N bytes from the input without storing them in your tuple, since you don't care about their values (ie, skip over them).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is combine C preprocessor with C++ operators. Write a couple of C++ classes like this one:

```
#include "immintrin.h"

class FlippedInt32
{
    int value;
public:
    inline operator int() const
    {
        return _bswap( value );
    }
};

class FlippedInt64
{
    __int64 value;
public:
    inline operator __int64() const
    {
        return _bswap64( value );
    }
};
```

Then,

```
#define int FlippedInt32
```

before including the header that define these structures. `#undef` immediately after the `#include`.

This will replace all `int` fields in the structures with `FlippedInt32`, which has the same size but returns flipped bytes.

If it’s your own structures which you can modify you don’t need the preprocessor part. Just replace the integers with the byte-flipping classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can come up with a list of offsets (in-bytes, relative to the top of the file) of the fields that need endian-conversion, as well as the size of those fields, then you could do all of the endian-conversion with a single for-loop, directly on the char array.  E.g. something like this (pseudocode):

```
struct EndianRecord {
   size_t offsetFromTop;
   size_t fieldSizeInByes;
};

std::vector<EndianRecord> todoList;
// [populate the todo list here...]

char * rawData = [pointer to the raw data]
for (size_t i=0; i<todoList.size(); i++)
{
   const EndianRecord & er = todoList[i];
   ByteSwap(&rawData[er.offsetFromTop], er.fieldSizeBytes);
}

struct MyPackedStruct * data = (struct MyPackedStruct *) rawData;
// Now you can just read the member variables
// as usual because you know they are already
// in the correct endian-format.
```

... of course the difficult part is coming up with the correct `todoList`, but since the file format is well-defined, it should be possible to generate it algorithmically (or better yet, create it as a generator with e.g. a `GetNextEndianRecord()` method that you can call, so that you don't have to store a very large vector in memory)